# STM32 C library for ILI9341 TFT LCD with 16-bit data bus?

Tags: arduino, stm32, lcd, tft, ili9341

I'm using FSMC with ILI9341 LCD and I have some troubles with the LCD.
The LCD comes in lot of different sorts, but this one do I have.

[image]

I'm using this library but the problem is that I get only two colors at my LCD screen. Black and Purple. That's because this library is made for 8-bit databus.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NUErX4dx2Tw

But You can still get things to work like geometry, text, pixels etc with this library if you have this settings.

[image]

**Question:**

I'm looking for a C library that can be used for 16-bit data bus. I have been looking at Github, but the only C libraries I found with 16-bit data bus is not suitable for STM32 or Arduino. Do you know one?

I know that there is a high intrerest in this question because 16-bit data bus for ILI9341 is quite rare.

Comment: Since the bus selection is set by a pin on the ILI9341 rather than by writing to a register, the device driver may differ only in that a write to graphics memory is 16 bits rather than 8, and that may well be device-specific anyway depending on which pins are being used (memory-mapped vs bit-banged).  As you’ve observed, an 8-bit library almost works without modification.

Comment: What prevents you from modifying the source code to work with your specific display?

Comment: @Justme I don't know what to do. Sure, I know how to send 16-bits directly, instead of 8-bits. But how should I shape the message?

Comment: Have you looked at ILI9341 datasheet?

Comment: @Justme Yes. But I don't know where to start. Does ILI9341 manufacturer give out an example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working library for 16-bit bus for ILI9341

https://github.com/taburyak/STM32-ILI9341-320x240-FSMC-Library

Don't forget to pull LCD RESET High! Cost me 2 days!